# does the order at which HDMI differential signals should be connected matter?

Tags: display, hdmi

I have 8 DDI (Digital Display Interface) signals that come out of the CPU with a certain numbering from 0 to 3.
I want to connect these signals to HDMI connector.
I was wondering if there is an importance for the order at which these signals should be wired at the HDMI connector, should they correspond to D2, D1, D0 and CK in the HDMI port in terms of numbering?

[image]

Comment: Yes it should match the intended receiver.  BTW are you using 10 bit Transition Minimized
Differential Signalling.

Comment: Thanks @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, do you think the way I connected them is O.K?

Comment: I don't know what is on each and your display type

Comment: Of course it matters. You must read your CPU manual how to connect them, if it even can be directly connected to HDMI connector, or if the chip does not have native HDMI support, then you need a conversion chip.